# Automating Curl Request Authorization

Tags: curl, google-sheets-api

I wanted to access a private google sheet. For that I have set up my Project in Google Cloud Console and obtained API key and OAuth2.0 client and secret keys.

I need to get Postman to be authorized to access the particular sheet. So, I have chosen OAuth2.0 autorization type and provided the necessary configurations. Then I have clicked `Get New Access Token` and provided the necessary consents and obtained the `Access Token`.

This `Access Token` should be provided in the request header while sending the request to get access to the private sheet.

My concern is can't we automate the process of getting the `Access Token` by just giving the necessary keys and other endpoint urls. (By using the `client_secret.json` file generated from Google Cloud Console Project)

Answer (score 0):

In your case the best option is using a [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts), these types of accounts are intended for non-human access.

Examples:

- Running workloads on virtual machines (VMs).
- Running workloads on on-premises workstations or data centers that call Google APIs.
- Running workloads which are not tied to the lifecycle of a human user.

Comment: Is there any sample curl requests using Service Account?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest